# Linking an object or class to GoogleMap marker

Tags: java, android, marker, google-maps-android-api-2

In a GoogleMap app, I am currently using markers to mark ship positions. I have made a `Ship`
class that records many properties such as ship name, latitude, longitude, MMSI code, etc. When a user clicks on one of the many markers on the map, a resulting clickable info window opens. When that user clicks the info window, another Activity is opened showing detailed information about that marker.

Well at least that last sentence is what I want. I can extract latitude and longitude positions but not much else. The problem is, although I have a `Ship` class with all the information I need, it isn't connected to the marker in any referential way, neither do I know how to do such a thing!

My best idea was to make `Ship` extend Marker, but that is a `final` class according to Eclipse IDE, and therefore cannot be extended.

This is my `Ship` class:

```java
public class Ship {

    /** Ship has the following properties
     *  */
    private String shipname = "";
    private String MMSI = "XXXX";
    private double[] loc = new double[2];

    public Ship(String _shipname, String _MMSI, double[] _loc) {
        shipname = _shipname;
        MMSI = _MMSI;
        loc[0] = _loc[0]; // Latitude
        loc[1] = _loc[1]; // Longitude

    }
    public String getName() {
        return shipname;
    }
    public String getMMSI() {
        return MMSI;
    }
    public double getLat() {
        return loc[0];
    }
    public double getLongi() {
        return loc[1];
    }
}
```

While, the `GoogleMap` markers are inserted dynamically via:

```java
public void setupRegion(GoogleMap map, ArrayList<Ship> ships) throws IOException {
        for(Ship ship : ships) {
            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
               .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.marker_red))
               .position(new LatLng(ship.getLat(), ship.getLongi()))
               .title(ship.getName())
               .snippet("Simulate"));
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of populating `snippet()` with `"Simulate"`, populate it with some unique identifier of your `Ship`, such that you can look up the `Ship` in the `Dock` or `Wharf` or `Shipyard` or `OnePercenterYachtClub` or `HashMap<String,Ship>` or wherever you store your `Ship` instances.

You will also need to set up an `InfoWindowAdapter`, so you can customize your info window contents to not show the snippet, assuming that you are using info windows.

Answer (score 1):

A commonly used solution is to keep a `Map<Marker, Ship>` in your Activity and do `map.get(marker)` inside `onInfoWindowClick` callback (or any other).

You can also try my library, which adds `Marker.setData(Object)` and `Marker.getData()` functions, so you can put Ship instances there after you create markers and get them back inside `onInfoWindowClick` callback.

http://code.google.com/p/android-maps-extensions/